# VBA Create Function option

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a function which returns me value based on the Month. Like if month is January then it will return me value "Qtr 1". The problem is I have to input the month in double quotes when using the function in Excel or else Excel gives me #value error.

```
Function quarter(m As String) As String

If m = "January" Or m = "February" Or m = "March" Then
quarter = "Qtr 1"
ElseIf m = "April" Or m = "May" Or m = "June" Then
quarter = "Qtr 2"
ElseIf m = "July" Or m = "August" Or m = "September" Then
quarter = "Qtr 3"
Else: quarter = "Qtr 4"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Please do clarify why that is a problem (e.g. describe a practical example). If you have the month written in another cell, you won't have to use double quotes.

Comment: Yes, strings are supposed to be in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this screenshot (based on your User Defined Function (UDF)), this is indeed correct and it is working properly:

[image]

As you can see, no double quotes are need (nor allowed) in your Excel cells, but I imagine this is not the basic idea, so everything seems to be working fine.

The usage of the double quotes in your VBA macro is basic VBA syntax.